# PHP error_log viewer for MAC

Tags: php, macos, google-chrome, error-logging

Does anyone know a good PHP error log viewer with color highlighting for MAC or Chrome Browser?

Cheers
Ken

Answer (score 2):

This will help make your error log a bit more readable: http://www.offsky.com/software/logdigester/index.php